# Programmatically set date of NgbDatePicker

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ngb-datepicker

I've two NgbDatePicker in my component:

```
      input(
        type="text",
        ngbDatepicker,
        #d="ngbDatepicker",
        [readonly]="true",
        formControlName='startDate',
        (dateSelect)='setNewMinDate($event)',
        )
      input(
        type="text",
        ngbDatepicker,
        #e="ngbDatepicker",
        [readonly]="true"
        formControlName='endDate'
        )
```

and this handler:

```
  @ViewChild('e', {static: false}) endDateComponent: Query;

  setNewMinDate(e: NgbDateStruct) {
    const minDate: Moment = moment(e.year + '-' + e.month + '-' + e.day);

    this.createAnnForm.value.endDate = minDate.toISOString();
    this.endDateComponent.navigateTo(e);
  }
```

Form model works with ISO date.

What happens is that the calendar popup change is date to the new one, but the input field doesn't update itself. What is the problem?

Comment: You mean input field is not gettting updated?

Comment: You're using Reactive Forms, just give value using `myform.get('endDate').setValue(...)`

Comment: If you want your form control to contain an ISO Date string, then you should use a date adapter. See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model for the documentation. You'll have to write an adapter to convert from string to NgbDateStruct and vice-versa.

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes

Comment: As @Eliseo mentioned in the comment you can use setValue or patchValue to set date to input field

Answer (score 0):

Ad @Eliseo suggests, I need to use ReativeForm API

```
form.get('endDate').setValue(...)
```

to update input fields